# ngx-pipes filter by multiple conditions

Tags: angular, pipe

I'm using ngx-pipes plugin(https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#filterby) in my ANgular project. And I don't find a way to filter by multiple properties.

My data looks like this

```
[{'name': 'tom', 'age':12, location:'denver'},
{'name': 'jerry', 'age':11, location:'denver'},
{'name': 'scott', 'age':12, location:'denver'}, 
{'name': 'tiger', 'age':13, location:'colarado'},
{'name': 'lion', 'age':11, location:'denver'}]
```

Now, I want to use filterBy pipe to filter the data whose age is 11, and whose location is 'Denver'.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can [chain](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#chaining-pipes) pipes.

```
p>{{ users | filterBy: ['age']: 11 | filterBy: ['location']: 'Denver' }}</p>
```

If you have a large array this may cause performance issues. This is the reason why angular 2+ do not have a filter pipe implemented. Keep this in mind. Read [this](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) for better understanding.